# Accurate determination of resistance of transformer

Tags: transformer

Based on this transformer:

[image]

Is it accurate that you can get the resistance of utility pole transformers simply by getting the xformer powerlosses at full load and deduct it to the xformer powerlosses at no load, then dividing it by xformer rated current squared as in the following?

Powerlosses noload=43 W [mainly magnetic core losses only-negligible copper losses]

Powerlosses fulload=758 W [magnetic core losses and copper losses]

Irated=75000/240=312.5A

Resistance of transformer = [Powerlosses fulload- Powerlosses noload] /Irated^2= 0.0073216 ohm.

Is the above accurate?

Comment: That would imply Isc= 32.8kA and Zo=0.95%pu That's pretty efficient

Comment: It's usually much higher than this so verify your losses or actual VA with temp rise.  Normally R is measured by stable CC

Comment: What is CC? Please see picture of the actual transformer nameplate above? How much higher can the R be compared to the computed 0.0073216 ohm (is the computation accurate above)?

Comment: Label says Zo=2.59%

Comment: Then you need to know X/R ratio to derive R from Zo. CC is constant current source like 1A then degauss afterwards to measure V=R of secondary

Comment: I don't know the X/R ratio, I just know Z. That is why I need to get R to solve for X. isn't the computed Resistance accurate? how many percentage can it go higher further?

Comment: Zo is mostly X as X/R >>10

Comment: The full 240 volt winding is rated 75 kVA. The impedance of a load that would draw 75 kVA is 240^2/75000 = 0.768 ohms. The transformer impedance is 2.59% or 0.0259 x 0.768 = 0.0198912 ohm. If R is really 0.0073216ohm. Then X is Xfr=√(Zxfr^2-Rxfr^2)= 0.0184947 ohm. so X/R ratio is 2.57. Is X/R ratio of 2.57 for the above transformer possible?

Comment: Sounds right lumping pri+sec together Line-line

Comment: Using the CC and degauss method.. how many percentage estimate if further increase of the resistance of 0.0073216 ohm. what do you think?

Comment: THis method determines primary and secondary Rs separately

Comment: So the computed R of 0.0073216 ohm is only for the secondary? Meaning the R of primary has to be determined too? Usually how big or small is it compared to the secondary R?

Comment: No you computed total losses in pri. & sec. and it depends

Comment: It's actually a 3 phase open delta composed of 2 individual transformers like that (not single 3 phase transformer).  so for the 2 individual transformers connected as3 phase open delta.. so you need to get the resistance of primary of each or just one (the first one)? please see https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/5857/efOTgQ.jpg

Comment: please see this post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426595/short-circuit-current-of-3-phase-open-delta-transformer/427153?noredirect=1#comment1070912_427153 it's the same transformers connected as 3 phase and we were determining the short circuit current. My question in this post is the resistances. So I guess without using CC and degauss. the value computed for R is never accurate. Can you give an example of transformer where the CC and degauss is measured? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.omicronenergy.com/en/download/document/4E9D31D1-FBB6-46CD-8DF1-938BA0496CB2/

Comment: based on experience or what you read.. how large is the discrepancy or percentage difference between method where the power loss at full load minus no load method is used versus the one you mentioned where constant current and degauss is used? The latter is hard and mostly unavailable so if one will rely on the former for short circuit computations in conjunction wiring to produce bolted short circuit current computations. I wonder how accurate is the R.

Comment: I suggest you get an RLC meter

Comment: How about Z? is the testing accurate or does it also needs to take into account actual VA with temp rise? And must be measured by stable CC  too? Note that "The percentage impedance of a transformer is the voltage drop on full load due to the winding resistance and leakage reactance expressed as a percentage of the rated voltage."